# como traer valores del mismo campo con distintas condiciones sin hacer subconsultas?

Tags: mysql-workbench

quisiera saber si me pueden ayudar a optimizar esta consulta.
Me trae los datos que necesito pero tarda mucho intento ver la manera de no hacer las subconsultas pero no encuentro el camino. No necesito necesariamente que me den la respuesta sino que me puedan ayudar alguien guiandome.

```
case
    when cant100 = cant250 then cant250
    when cant100 > cant250 then cant250
    when cant100 < cant250 then cant100
end as resultado
from(
    select so.SerNr, count(*) as cant100
    from SalesOrder as so
    inner join SalesOrderItemRow as soir
    on so.internalId = soir.masterId
    where soir.ArtCode in ('05100000', '05100001','05100002','05100003')
    group by so.SerNr
    ) as t1
inner join
    (
    select so.SerNr, count(*) as cant250
    from SalesOrder as so
    inner join SalesOrderItemRow as soir
    on so.internalId = soir.masterId
    where soir.ArtCode in ('05100014', '05100015','05100016','05100017')
    group by so.SerNr
    ) as t2
on t1.SerNr = t2.SerNr
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

que bueno que preguntes esto, tengo una posible soluciòn a tu pregunta.

```
    SELECT 
    Gen.SerNr,
    Gen.cant100,
    Gen.cant250,
    CASE
        WHEN cant100 = cant250 THEN cant250
        WHEN cant100 > cant250 THEN cant250
        WHEN cant100 < cant250 THEN cant100
    END AS Result
FROM
    (SELECT 
        so.SerNr,
            SUM(IF(soir.ArtCode IN ('05100000' , '05100001', '05100002', '05100003'), 1, 0)) AS cant100,
            SUM(IF(soir.ArtCode IN ('05100014' , '05100015', '05100016', '05100017'), 1, 0)) AS cant250
    FROM
        SalesOrder AS so
    LEFT JOIN SalesOrderItemRow AS soir ON so.internalId = soir.masterId
    WHERE
        so.SerNr = '1000147063') AS Gen
;
```

Comment: Deberías explicar tu respuesta compañero, checa [answer], editar y agregar contexto ayudará a que sea fácil de entender y aplicar por todos quienes consulten

Answer (score 0):

buenas tardes tengo otra posible respuesta a esta duda, espero les sirva.

````
    SUM(IF(soir.ArtCode IN ('05100000' , '05100001', '05100002', '05100003'),
        soir.Qty,
        0)) AS cant100,
    SUM(IF(soir.ArtCode IN ('05100014' , '05100015', '05100016', '05100017'),
        soir.Qty,
        0)) AS cant250,
    CASE
        WHEN
            SUM(IF(soir.ArtCode IN ('05100000' , '05100001', '05100002', '05100003'),
                soir.Qty,
                0)) = SUM(IF(soir.ArtCode IN ('05100014' , '05100015', '05100016', '05100017'),
                soir.Qty,
                0))
        THEN
            SUM(IF(soir.ArtCode IN ('05100000' , '05100001', '05100002', '05100003'),
                soir.Qty,
                0))
        WHEN
            SUM(IF(soir.ArtCode IN ('05100000' , '05100001', '05100002', '05100003'),
                soir.Qty,
                0)) > SUM(IF(soir.ArtCode IN ('05100000' , '05100001', '05100002', '05100003'),
                soir.Qty,
                0))
        THEN
            SUM(IF(soir.ArtCode IN ('05100000' , '05100001', '05100002', '05100003'),
                soir.Qty,
                0))
        WHEN
            SUM(IF(soir.ArtCode IN ('05100000' , '05100001', '05100002', '05100003'),
                soir.Qty,
                0)) < SUM(IF(soir.ArtCode IN ('05100014' , '05100015', '05100016', '05100017'),
                soir.Qty,
                0))
        THEN
            SUM(IF(soir.ArtCode IN ('05100000' , '05100001', '05100002', '05100003'),
                soir.Qty,
                0))
    END AS Result,
    so.SerNr
FROM
    SalesOrder AS so
        INNER JOIN
    SalesOrderItemRow AS soir ON so.internalId = soir.masterId
GROUP BY so.SerNr```
````

Comment: Asumo que tu idea era publicar una pregunta y respuesta lo cual esta bien, pero ayudará mucho mas creeme que expliques tu código pues al momento la respuesta carece un tanto de calidad por lo mismo